# How can I do a case-sensitive search in Emacs?

Tags: search, emacs, case-sensitive

Is there a shortcut? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> gives `I-search:`, and that is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You press <kbd>M-c</kbd> after you run search.

This will set the case-sensitive flag.

More generally, you can do: <kbd>C-s</kbd> <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> to see all keybindings active during search, in `isearch-mode-map`.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to `M-c` mentioned by alinsoar, entering a capital letter as part of your search string will cause the search to be case-sensitive.

Comment: should capital letter entered as the first character?

Comment: Not much use if you're searching for a lower-case string... :)